# How to create Intellij idea maven/gradle plugin which checks code-quality at real time?

Tags: java, checkstyle, sonarlint, static-code-analysis, maven-checkstyle-plugin

For one of my application, which deals with many yaml files, I was using the **YamlLint** plugin which validates the yaml files. the plugin is very useful but the only problem with this plugin is it only tells you the 1st syntax error of your yaml file. when you correct the first error then only it will show you the 2nd syntax error and so on. Also, this plugin does not work in real time. we have to run the **yamllint** command to run it.

As at every yamllint command run, it tells us only one syntax error. it takes very much time to check the complete yaml file for errors.

To overcome this problem, I am designing my own plugin. can anyone tell be how can I setup my plugin to work at real time and I do not have to run the command everytime to check for errors.(like sonarlint do).

Comment: This question is very broad. I suggest you start with any of the plugin tutorials available on the net or to look at existing plugins: https://www.baeldung.com/intellij-new-custom-plugin